# Resolve __typename union

Tags: typescript, graphql

Say I have this union:

```
export type IBookmarkItemFragment =
  | ({ __typename: "Story" } & {
      story: number;
    })
  | ({ __typename: "Product" } & {
      product: number;
    })
  | ({ __typename: "Project" } & {
      project: number;
    });
```

I want `.filter` and `.map` based off `__typeame`. Something like:

```
bookmarks
  .filter(bookmark => {
    return bookmark.__typename === "Project";
  })
  .map(project => {
    return project.project;
  });
```

How can I make sure that in the map `project` will resolve to:

```
({ __typename: "Project" } & {
  project: number;
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly declare the function is a type guard with an annotation:

```
export type IBookmarkItemFragment =
| ({ __typename: "Story" } & {
    story: number;
    })
| ({ __typename: "Product" } & {
    product: number;
    })
| ({ __typename: "Project" } & {
    project: number;
    });

declare let bookmarks: IBookmarkItemFragment[]
bookmarks
.filter((bookmark):bookmark is Extract<IBookmarkItemFragment, { __typename: "Project"}>   => {
    return bookmark.__typename === "Project";
})
.map(project => {
    return project.project;
});
```

Or just for fun if we want to generalize the type guard, we can create a guard factory that will work for this any common tagged union.

```
export type IBookmarkItemFragment =
| ({ __typename: "Story" } & {
    story: number;
    })
| ({ __typename: "Product" } & {
    product: number;
    })
| ({ __typename: "Project" } & {
    project: number;
    });

function guardFactory<T, K extends keyof T, V extends string & T[K]>(k: K, v: V) : (o: T) => o is Extract<T, Record<K, V>> {
    return function (o: T): o is Extract<T, Record<K, V>> {
        return o[k] === v
    }
}
declare let bookmarks: IBookmarkItemFragment[]
bookmarks
.filter(guardFactory("__typename", "Project"))
.map(project => {
    return project.project;
});
```

Comment: Excellent answer! How'd you make `__typename` a constant? Say I want to use it like: `.filter(byTypename("Project"))`

Comment: It need to know the tagged field so you either change the `guardFactory` to only work for types with `__typename`  or you have to specify it like I did above. `__typename` is a `keyof T`, so it will be checked against the expected item type. The trick here is that `T` can be inferred from return type. So using it directly in filter is a must, as it allows us to know what union we are discriminating